# C# A quick way to find out if a network path is available using NetBEUI protocol

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming, network-protocols

Im writing a application that reads logs from 1-many computers in the network. The network computers with the logs dont have tcp/ip installed, they are using NetBEUI protocol instead.
So i access them with "\\computername\c$\path-to-logs"

My question is, how can i access them without having to wait for the long network wait if the network is not available? It could be 1 computer with logs...and it could be up to 5

Example:
check \\computer1\c$\path-to-logs ...found it, copy logs

check \\computer2\c$\path-to-logs ...found it, copy logs

check \\computer3\c$\path-to-logs ...didnt find it (here is normally a long wait before i get the timeout that it doesnt exist)

Best regards Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andreas,
simplest solution is to make it multi-thread, to open a thread per remote PC.
In communication, you always need to pay attention to communication- time - out when one of the PC's is not available. Multi threading with limiting communication time out is the solution I usually using.

Comment: Hi yeah this was the way i was thinking to do it. Just wanted to know if there was a magic builtin way with a windows driver to import or something that would let me know asap if that path was valid or not